# If $\bigg|1+\sum_{k=2}^Ne^{2\pi i b_kc}\bigg|=N,$ how to prove that $e^{2\pi i b_kc}=1$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose that  $c$ is a real number and $0,b_2,\ldots,b_N$ are integers. If
$$\bigg|1+\sum_{k=2}^Ne^{2\pi i b_kc}\bigg|=N,$$
how to prove that $e^{2\pi i b_kc}=1$ for any $k=2,\ldots,N$?

The hint is :the terms in the sum differ by a positive multiplicative constant. But I don't understand it. Can somebody help me? Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose there exists some $2\le m\le N$ such that $e^{2\pi ib_mc}\ne1$. Then we have

$$
\left|1+\sum_{k=2}^Ne^{2\pi ib_kc}\right|\le|1+e^{2\pi ib_mc}|+N-2.\tag1
$$

Notice that

$$
|1+e^{2\pi ib_mc}|=|e^{\pi ib_mc}|\cdot|e^{-\pi ib_mc}+e^{\pi ib_mc}|=2|\cos(\pi b_mc)|.\tag2
$$

Since $e^{2\pi ib_mc}\ne1$ if and only if $b_mc$ is not an integer, we conclude the right-hand side of (2) is $<2$. This indicates that the right-hand side of (1) is $<N$, which is a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

$$\left|e^{2\pi \mathbf{i}b_kc}  \right| = 1  \hspace{1cm} \forall k$$
(attention, the *absolute value* of $e^{2\pi \mathbf{i}b_kc}$ is equal to $1$)

and the inequality
$$\left|\sum_{k=1}^n a_k\right| \le \sum_{k=1}^n\left| a_k\right| $$

Answer (score 1):

*Hint.* It suffices to prove a more general result:

> **Theorem.** Let $N \geq 1$ be a positive integer. Then for any complex numbers $z_1, \ldots, z_N$, the followings are equivalent:
>
> 1. $|z_1+\cdots+z_N|=|z_1|+\cdots+|z_N|$.
> 2. $z_1, \ldots, z_N$ are all in the same direction, that is, there exists $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}$ with $|\alpha|=1$ such that $z_k=\alpha|z_k|$ for all $k=1,\ldots,N$.

$(2) \Rightarrow (1)$ is trivial, and $(1) \Rightarrow (2)$ can be easily proved in various ways, for instance invoking mathematical induction or Cauchy–Schwarz inequality.

Comment: How $1$ is true? If we take $z_1=1$ and $z_2=-2$ then LHS would be $1$ and RHS would be $3$.

Comment: @LuckyChouhan, The statement means that "if $(1)$ holds, then $(2)$ also holds, and vice versa." It is basically a conditional statement.

Answer (score 1):

I will proceed inductively and for general unitary complex numbers. For the case $N=2$ we have

> **Lemma:** If $a,b$ are unitary complex numbers such that $|a+b|=2$ then $a=b$.

> **Proof:**  We may write $a=e^{i\alpha}$, $b=e^{i\beta}$, for some arguments $\alpha,\beta$. Then
> \begin{equation*}
>     a+b=(\cos(\alpha)+\cos(\beta))+i(\sin(\alpha)+\sin(\beta)).
> \end{equation*}
> Using trigonometric identities we obtain the following equality,
> \begin{equation*}
>     a+b=2\cos\left(\frac{\alpha-\beta}{2}\right)\left(\cos\left(\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}\right)+i\sin\left(\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}\right)\right).
> \end{equation*}
> Since $|a+b|=2$ it follows that $\left|\cos\left(\frac{\alpha-\beta}{2}\right)\right|=1$ and this forces that $\frac{\alpha-\beta}{2}=k\pi$ for some integer $k$. Now, we have that $\alpha=\beta+2k\pi$, from where we conclude that $a=b$.

Now, we denote $\varepsilon_1=1$, $\varepsilon_k=e^{2\pi ib_kc}$ for $k\geq 2$. Then,
\begin{equation*}
    \sum_{k=1}^N|\varepsilon_k|=N=|\sum_{k=1}^N\varepsilon_k|.
\end{equation*}
If we take $1\leq j\leq N$, applying the triangle inequality to the previous equality we have that
\begin{equation*}        \sum_{k\not=j}|\varepsilon_k|+|\varepsilon_j|=\sum_{k=1}^N|\varepsilon_k|=|\sum_{k=1}^N\varepsilon_k|\leq|\sum_{k\not=j}\varepsilon_k|+|\varepsilon_j|\leq\sum_{k\not=j}|\varepsilon_k|+|\varepsilon_j|.
\end{equation*}
Subtracting $|\varepsilon_j|$ we obtain that
\begin{equation*} \sum_{k\not=j}|\varepsilon_k|=|\sum_{k\not=j}\varepsilon_k|.
\end{equation*}
Proceeding inductively, we arrive to
\begin{equation*}
    2=|\varepsilon_1|+|\varepsilon_k|=|\varepsilon_1+\varepsilon_k|
\end{equation*}
for each $k$. Therefore, using the previous Lemma we conclude that $\varepsilon_k=\varepsilon_1=1$ for all $k$.